# Compatibility with Gnu Free Documentation License

Tags: discussion, licensing

Can questions be asked on StackOverflow and then answers be contributed to projects licensed under the Gnu free documentation License (such as [PLEAC](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/)).

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

All content is licensed under [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 2.5 Generic.](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) So any usage of code from here is subject to that license.

Answer (score 1):

IANAL, so grain of salt and all that.

I believe that you can (try to) contact the original poster to obtain permission to use it in a GPL context. Because the copyright holder can license the creation several different ways if they so desire.

If this sounds like the way you want to go, contact a IP lawyer.